# Second part to: write two functions that reverse the order of the elements in a vect<int>

Tags: c++, function, vector

First of all, I do know that someone asked the following question. However, they did not ask the second part. I need help in the second part.

Write two functions that reverse the order of elements in a vector. For example, 1,3,5,7,9 becomes 9,7,5,3,1. The second reverse function should reverse the elements of its vector w/o using any other vectors. (hint: swap).

But when I test my code. It doesn't reverse the order with the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testing.size(); i++) 
    swap(testing[i], testing[testing.size() - 1 - i]);
```

But when I divide testing.size() by 2. It works perfectly. So my question is: why does it work when it's divided by two. I've looked for a good amount of time and even tried sketching it out.

```
for (int i = 0; i < testing.size()/2; i++) 
    swap(testing[i], testing[testing.size() - 1 - i]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Here's the entire coding:

```
void replacing(vector<int>& testing)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < testing.size(); i++)
        cout << "original " << testing[i] << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < testing.size(); i++)
        swap(testing[i], testing[testing.size() - 1 - i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < testing.size(); i++) 
        cout << "reversed " << testing[i] << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> original;
    int numbers;

    cout << "Enter random numbers: \n";
    while (cin >> numbers) 
        original.push_back(numbers);

    replacing(original);
}
```

Comment: `std::reverse(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());` [easy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).  cppreference also has the "possible implementation" shown

Comment: That'll be useful for future projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the purposes of illustration, here’s what’s happening in a sample run of your program. `i` is moving rightward and `size() - 1 - i` (call it `j`) is moving leftward:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
i         j

6 2 3 4 5 1
  i     j

6 5 3 4 2 1
    i j

6 5 4 3 2 1
    j i
```

Your loop should stop here, because `i` has exceeded `size() / 2`. Now watch:

```
6 5 3 4 2 1
    j i

6 2 3 4 5 1
  j     i

1 2 3 4 5 6
j         i
```

It actually stops here, when `i` reaches `size()`, whereupon all the elements that you swapped have been swapped back to their original locations!

Comment: Thanks! I'm more of a visual learner. So with your visual aid and Vlad's answer, I was able to get it.

Answer (score 2):

To reverse a vector you need to swap its two halves. If you swap its halves two times you will get again the original vector.

So this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < testing.size(); i++) 
{

    swap(testing[i], testing[testing.size() - 1 - i]);

}
```

swaps two halves when `i < testing.size() / 2` and then when `i >= testing.size() / 2` again swaps these halves restoring the original order of the vector.

So a correct loop will look like

```
for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < testing.size() / 2; i++ ) 
{

    swap( testing[i], testing[testing.size() - 1 - i] );
}
```

In this case you swap each element with index less than `testing.size() / 2` (low half) with each element with index gretaer than or equal to `testing.size() / 2`(upper half)

You could write the function with one statement

```
testing.assign( testing.rbegin(), testing.rend() );
```

Also there is a standard algorithm declared in header `<algorithm>` that does the same

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::reverse( testing.begin(), testing.end() );
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to finish my homework on time. We haven't learned about reverse() yet, and it seems like the teacher only wants us to use code that we have gone over. But I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you have (i < testing.size()) you will first switch all of the numbers, but you will just switch all of them back to where they were first afterwards. So if you have a vector with values {0,1,2,3}, you would switch 0 with 3, 1 with 2, then it would continue and switch 1 back with 2 and 3 back with 0 to make {0,1,2,3} again.  When you divide it by 2, it stops before it can start switching the numbers back to what they were first and you get the vector you want.